# Applying multiplication and division across all items in my NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *numberOfRides = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<30; i++)
        [numberOfRides addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];

NSMutableArray*targetDollarAdd = numberOfRides;
    for (NSInteger e=0; e<30; e++)
        [targetDollarAdd replaceObjectAtIndex:e withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:e] * [NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.75];
```

I'm brand new to programming. I'm trying to multiply everything in my array by 2.75, but I keep getting errors. I've tried searching, but everything seems to advanced for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't multiply NSNumbers. They aren't numbers! They are objects wrapping numbers.

But you can't keep numbers in an NSArray. They aren't objects! That's what an NSNumber is for: to wrap an number up in an object so you can do things like keep it in an NSArray. Oh, the irony!

So, to do arithmetic on an NSNumber, unwrap the NSNumber (to get an integer or a double or whatever is inside it — use `integerValue` or `doubleValue` or whatever is appropriate), do the arithmetic, then wrap the result back up as an NSNumber (using `initWithDouble:` or whatever) and stick it back into the array.

Comment: May I suggest that if you find this difficult, you learn Swift instead of Objective-C? Problems such as this don't arise there.